# Node.js Cluster not listening

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a "Hello World" multi-process node.js HTTP server.

Using the code samples provided in the node docs [here](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) I can't get the "listening" event to fire, and thus an HTTP server to respond to requests. I am, however, getting the "online" event to fire.

How can I get this server to respond to requests?

I'm running on OSX 10.8.4, node v0.10.7.

Here's what I have:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
    console.log('A worker with #' + worker.id);
  });
  cluster.on('listening', function(worker, address) {
    console.log('A worker is now connected to ' + address.address + ':' + address.port);
  });
  cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case its a HTTP server
  http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);
}
```

Comment: The sample code you posted works just fine for me.  Double check numCPUs is greater than 0???

Comment: It prints "8" and so 8 processes are forked. Does the sample code actually receive and respond to HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes, using your sample code, I visit the following link in a browswer: http://localhost:8000.  I see hello world.  I'm on OSX 10.8.4, Node v0.8.2 (little old).

Comment: Maybe it was broken in node 0.10

Comment: So you know, it works for me on both a Ubuntu nitrous.io box running v0.10.11 and on Mac OS X 10.8.4 running v0.10.12. I don't know why it wouldn't be working for you -- the only think I can think of is to triple check that you're visiting http://localhost:8000.

Comment: Not sure if its relevant to your problem, but I have once seen that to use non standard ports, you'll have to have root permissions. So make sure you using `sudo` while running your app.

Comment: Just started out with node 5.11.0 && Mac OS X 10.11.4, seeing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by running the file directly. Previously, I ran server.js which was a one liner:

*server.js*

```
require("./server/app.js");
```

*server/app.js* (code snippet in the question)

By running `node app.js` instead of `node server.js` the cluster started listening. Not sure why this made a difference.